# AbsoluteURI support in Play Framework 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.1

As stated here:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

> To allow for transition to absoluteURIs in all requests in future versions of HTTP, all HTTP/1.1 servers MUST accept the absoluteURI form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only generate them in requests to proxies.

I have client which sends POST-requests to my play-2.1.1 server. He sends it this way:

```
POST http://172.16.1.227:9000/A8%3aF9%3a4B%3a20%3a89%3a40/1089820966/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 473
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 15:44:43 GMT
Host: 172.16.1.227:9000
User-Agent: my-client

...some data...
```

All requests are rejected with "Action not found" error. The very same request which I send using curl is just fine and the only difference between them is curl send it with relative URI:

```
POST /A8%3aF9%3a4B%3a20%3a89%3a40/1089820966/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 593
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 172.16.1.227:9000
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
```

I created the following simple workaround in Global.scala:

```
override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
  if (request.path.startsWith("http://")) {
    super.onRouteRequest(request.copy(
      path = request.path.replace("http://"+request.host, "")
    ))
  } else super.onRouteRequest(request)
}
```

And with this workaround all requests from my client are handled correctly.

So, is there more straightforward way to do it in Play Framework or thats the only way?

Comment: You should post this subject on the Play mailing link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/play-framework

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@nraychaudhuri](https://github.com/nraychaudhuri) Play 2.2 supports `absoluteURI`-style request headers.

Here's the issue and pull request: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1060